# How to Count lists within HTML structure (Selenium)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have HTML with the following structure and wish to how the inner most li's:

```
<div id="topDiv" ..... >
    <div ...... >
        <ul class="lists" ...>
            <li .....>
                <ul ....>
                    <li id="importantlist1">
                    <li id="importantlist2">
                    ...
                    ...
                </ul>
           </li>
       </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to use the selenium web driver to count the "important" li's. Like how many there are total. The top div and first ul has id's as well as each important li. I tried various things using cssSelector, xpath and findElements(By.id().... but I cannot get it right. Any help? Thanks

Comment: "I tried various things" is usually not good enough. We need to see exact details.

Answer (score 2):

From the little code you supplied, `driver.findElements(By.xpath("//li[contains(@id, 'importantlist')]")).size()` should work.